# Kivy instantiating widgets dynamically and based on mouse click

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I am new to kivy. I am trying to create a simple application which works on detecting mouse click and draws a circle based on the co-ordinates of the mouse. The below code is able to do it.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Color
from random import random



class MyAppleWidget(Widget):


    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        with self.canvas:
         Color(random(), 1, 1, 1)
         d = 30.0
         Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
         

class MyAppleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyAppleWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyAppleApp().run()
```

Kivy file -- dummy file to pop up a circle at the begining

```
<MyAppleWidget>:
    canvas:
        Color: 
            rgb: random(), 1,1
        Ellipse:
            pos: root.center
            size: 10, 10
```

I was wondering if there was a way to shift the code in the touch function to be shifted to the kivy file.. meaning.. can I define the canvas and drawing instruction in the kivy file and pass the touch points of the mouse while creating the widget dynamically. More like using the kivy file definition to create the circle widget based on the touch point co-ordinate. I tried with dynamic classes etc. but haven't been able to arrive at a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved like below:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

APP_KV = """
#:import random random
#:import Ellipse kivy.graphics.Ellipse
#:import Color kivy.graphics.Color
<MyAppleWidget>:
    d: 30.0
    on_touch_down: 
        self.collide_point(*args[1].pos)
        self.canvas.add(Color(random.random(), 1, 1))
        self.canvas.add(Ellipse(pos=(args[1].pos[0] - self.d / 2, args[1].pos[1] - self.d / 2), size=(self.d, self.d)))
"""

class MyAppleWidget(Widget):
    pass

class MyAppleApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_string(APP_KV)
        return MyAppleWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyAppleApp().run()
```

Comment: It depends on how you want this to be done. May be you can create an example scenario and then it can better clarified.

Comment: Thanks this works. Really helpful ! as I understand this correctly the right hand side of Kivy language can have some python code. Quick follow up - if there was a more generic scenario of handling some processing in python and then pass some arguments to create the widget... how would we be able to handle such scenario.. meaning let's say i calculate x, y and then instantiate the widget and pass x and y from python to kivy.. with kivy having the widget definition.

Comment: just to make it more clear.. i calculate x, y , color (this could be something else as well) in python on touch event... and then do something like WidgetCreate(x,y, color).. as we would do in python.. just that can I have that widget definition in Kivy..

Comment: scenario -> get an external user input.. mouse click position could be one.. another could be something like time elapsed from when the mouse was clicked and then released.. calculate a custom value based on this.. using these values fetch a random string from say a database.. and then instantiate a widget.. which displays the text retrieved from the database at the location of mouse click.. i would like to have the flexibility to define the widget in kivy, have the db calls in python for pre processing.  but instantiate it by passing some init values from python to widget defined in kivy